# Nine patch image not working on my device?

Tags: android, nine-patch

This is the first time i use nine-patch image on my android app. It so stupit. When I preview on eclipse layout editor, it work. But when I build the application on real device (HTC Inspire 4g, HTC Explorer,...) it's not.

```
<LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="0dip"
                        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_margin="5dp"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:background="@drawable/shadow_border"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:padding="0dip" >

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/itemdetail_textview_price"
                            style="@style/textview_nomalBold"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="$10"
                            android:textColor="#F00"
                            android:textSize="32dp" />

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/itemdetail_textview_originalPrice"
                            style="@style/textview_nomalBold"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                            android:text="$20"
                            android:textSize="32dp" />
                    </LinearLayout>
```

[image: On Nine patch tool]

[image: Preview on Eclipse layout Editor]

[image: On real device]

Is there any problem here?

UPDATED:

- I am writing the app for Android 2.2 and above.
- My Phones use Android 2.3

Comment: are you sure image name is `yourimgname.9.png?
`

Comment: what name of shadow_border..is it? `shadow_bordder.9.png`..check wheather in each drawable folder keeping the same file and all are correct..if there is only one..then its good..

Comment: The name of the image is "shadow_border.9.png". And it works when I preview on Eclipse Layout Editor

Comment: sometimes generated data does not work. Did you try to remove the `gen` folder, re-generate android R and rebuild project?

Comment: Yes, I did remove the gen folder then re-generate it. The problem still occurs.

Comment: if you are having drawable-mdpi, drawable-hdpi and drawable-ldpi folder, so just put `shadow_border` in all folder.

Comment: #louiscoquio If you are using Android Studio you should also delete and rebuild the "build" directory.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I solved it by my self but I don't understand why it works.

In nine-patch, I draw 2 line at the top and the left of image (see 2 black lines at the picture)
[image]

Answer (score 13):

Remove two dots from bottom and right side because these side decides in how much space your content should be displayed.

and here is how the nine patches work in android

[image: nine patch]

And Follow [this tutorial](http://android10.org/index.php/articlesother/279-draw-9-patch-tutorial) when you create a nine patch image.

Comment: but why it works on nine patch tool and on preview screen of  layout editor of eclipse?

Comment: @NguyenMinhBinh actually i dont know why they have given us a buggy tool i faced the same problem what you do thats y i had ans and i given it to you hopefully its working for you

Comment: The reason why it works in the tool and not in the application is because the tool is most likely calculating it more lazily than android. ie: the 9 patch tool looks for the left most and right most pixels and doesn't look at anything in between.

Answer (score 1):

I tested it more deeply, and it seems that there are inconsistencies between the draw9patch tool, Graphical editor in Eclipse and the device. Nine-patches, that seem to work in the first two, do not work on the device - they silently fall back to BitmapDrawable, without reporting an error. Reproduces on my 2.3.5 device, as well as in 4.1 emulator. See this android bug: http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=38941

Workaround is to draw single row of pixels, not just dots.

TIP: your image should be as small as possible. If you put two dots to the left or top region, it means, that you have two stretched areas and the area between them is kept unstretched. You can cut out the area from the first dot (excluded) to the second dot (included) and have only one dot, with a smaller image and the same result.

Comment: I created a bug report for this: http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=38941. I used your images :)

Answer (score 0):

The image I'm using has a shadow, and brilliantly I assumed that it ends before it reaches the last pixel of the image... and so didn't bother to enlarge the image by a pixel... (I know the 9 patch tool is doing this for me but I was in the middle of editing the image so I just added it there)

So the problem is The preview can handle pixels with alpha, the 9-patch tool can handle it as well, but the device cannot!