# my android spinner doesn't look fine

Tags: android, android-layout, spinner

I need to customize my android spinner. For this I created this spinner_selector.xml :

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:state_window_focused="false" android:state_enabled="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/spinner_default" />
    <item
        android:state_window_focused="false" android:state_enabled="false"
        android:drawable="@drawable/spinner_default" />
    <item
        android:state_pressed="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/spinner_pressed" />
    <item
        android:state_focused="true" android:state_enabled="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/spinner_focused" />
    <item
        android:state_enabled="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/spinner_default" />
    <item
        android:state_focused="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/spinner_focused" />
    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/spinner_default" />
</selector>
```

and then set the background of spinner : `android:background="@drawable/spinner_selector"`

The problem is that the spinner looks really horrible. Before : [image: http://i45.tinypic.com/2yjyavk.png]

After :

[image]

and when it is pressed, it looks like this :

The image that I use is this :

[image]

How to solve this? I have this problem for `Spinner`, `Button` and `EditText` too. I really need to customize these components. Please help. Any idea is welcome.

Comment: use nine patch image here is how to create one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10479001/nine-patch-image-not-working-on-my-device/10479866#10479866

Comment: provide xml code of spinner too and also check it's width, height properties

Comment: I have this : android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" for spinner

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To align text to right a bit, you can use `padding` in your XML please give Padding to the Spinner like this for ex: `android:padding=5dp`

Comment: It helped me to arrange the text. Thanks. And I set the height to the height of the image put as background.

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems is the height and width of the Spinner, your need to change it,
either you can give any static value or use wrap content with setting image size bigger.