# Bugs in Ninepatch graphics display

Tags: android, nine-patch

i try to use nine patch for a layout's background. However, some indicators in the nine patch is displayed. See this link-> http://dl.dropbox.com/u/78582670/NinePatchError.png

How do i remove the indicators??

my nested layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="#FFFEFEFE"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="0.5"
    android:text="@string/test1" />

<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/menu_bg2">

</FrameLayout>
```

Thanks you.

Comment: provide your original nine-patch picture please

Comment: try to create your nine patch image like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10479001/nine-patch-image-not-working-on-my-device/10479866#10479866

Comment: @Jin35: This is my nine-path picture - http://dl.dropbox.com/u/78582670/menu_bg2.9.png

Comment: @Akki: Thanks. i read it before, i just edit my nine-patch under Android tool - draw9patch.

Comment: Please mark one of the answers as the solution if it was correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you looked at the nine patch image itself? You should be able to open it with any graphics editing application. My feeling is that the 9 patch image is actually the problem here and not your layout. To fix this, should you confirm the image contains the errors, just rerun the slicing in the 9patch tool.

Comment: dl.dropbox.com/u/78582670/menu_bg2.9.png
Can you look at my nine-patch? What's problem for it?

Comment: You can see the lines in question on the image you linked. Definitely the result of the image itself and not your layout as I suspected. Also this is not a good use of 9 patch. 9 Patch is meant to help create 'stretchable' images in a format where you can describe to the layout what parts the image should be stretched and what parts should never be stretched.

Comment: is there no way to remove the black line and the graphics can be stretchable??

Comment: You could just edit out the lines but the problem is this image is not a good candidate for being used a 9 patch image. It has no parts in the image where stretching it would make sense. I think instead you should edit out the black lines (just crop it with whatever image editor you have) and use the image as is.

Comment: i get your point. i just want to test 9 patch. This image just a dummy image i try. But, if i design 9 patch for button. Does you see the black line around the button assume the background color is white.

Comment: You can find most of the vanilla resources here and view their 9 patch images. Just use these as an example of what yours should look like.
http://androiddrawableexplorer.appspot.com/

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is that you didn't make the 9 patch in the 9 patch tool. 
You have two black lines on the left for some reason when you should have one continuous black line on the left and another continuous black line on the top.

Also, I'm not really sure why you'd be using this particular image as a 9 patch. It makes no sense.

http://developer.android.com/tools/help/draw9patch.html This document explains what 9 patches are for and how to set them up correctly.

Comment: I just want to test the behavior of nine-patch only as i use it for a first time.