# Nine-patch image to draw 1 pixel border around TextView

Tags: android, nine-patch

[image]  <-- **This is a 3x3 image. Sorry.**

I use the following 3x3 images.

So, when I open with **draw9patch.bat**, and added 2 pixels on top and left respectively, I get the following images.

[image]

I expect if I apply this image to `TextView`, my entire `TextView` will have 1 pixel width border around itself.

However, I am only manage to get "half border". The borders at right and bottom are missing.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="#ffffff" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:background="@drawable/border" />

</LinearLayout>
```

[image]

Is there anything wrong with my 9 patch image?

[image] <-- **9 patch image for your testing purpose.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try adding 1px empty space around it. See attached image.

[image: padded bg]

Comment: OK. It seems to work now. But why we need to leave 1px empty space around it? Any explanation?

Comment: I have no idea. I was guessing that Android confuse the outermost pixel with the border somehow. Maybe they scale the image before doing the stretching stuff. Just a wild guess.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try adding the 2 pixels corresponding to the content, like so:

[image]

Comment: Nope. Didn't help. The result still the same.

Comment: Is the file saved as .9.png? Can you please post it here?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to astroturf, but I suggest you see my answer to this question: [how create Gradient like Iphone Edittext box in android](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11644429/517561)

Short answer: Try not to second-guess the platform.
Slightly longer answer: A [shape drawable](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#Shape) in your background will probably give better results.  The linked answer shows how to do this.