# nine patch image doesn't work

Tags: android, nine-patch

I did a 9 patch image with android tool draw9patch.bat. Draw a black line only on the right side, where I want it to stretch. Saved as .9.png and set it to background of TextView:

```
android:background="@drawable/myninepatch"
```

It doesn't work, I get the image with the black line in the app and it doesn't stretch. What am I doing wrong?

I have seen at some places besides of the lines for the stretchable area there's also a very small marked area in the opposite side, but I don't know what is it for and I'm not using it.

Comment: please check whether you have created a valid nine patch image or not follow this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10479001/nine-patch-image-not-working-on-my-device/10479866#10479866

Comment: what filename does it show in explorer?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check this [guideline](http://radleymarx.com/blog/simple-guide-to-9-patch/) .  Here you can find simple UI Guideline for nine patch images .

Answer (score 2):

In 9 patch images the right and bottom side lines indicate the padding, eg. the size which below the image won't shrink. The segment indicated by the top and left side line will stretch and shrink according to the desired size.