# No resource found after using .9.png from drawable

Tags: android, drawable

I am new to Android Studio.
I copied a `.9.png` into `drawable-hdpi` and used that image for the background.

But it is giving an error:

```
Error:(6, 25) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'background' with value '@drawable/spc').

  Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\software\new sdk\sdk\build-tools\23.0.0\aapt.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
```

How to solve this error?

Comment: Please show your implementation. Is there any typo?

Comment: @Christopher

here is the screen shot
https://www.dropbox.com/s/htfmyzj3vijkxhj/Capture.PNG?dl=0

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya
yes sir using 9 patcch

Answer (score 2):

At first clean and restart your IDE.

https://developer.android.com/studio/write/draw9patch.html

I think it's your **9-patch** image problem .

[Nine patch image not working on my device?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10479001/nine-patch-image-not-working-on-my-device)

Comment: @user3596211 Clean and rebuild your ide

Comment: @user3596211 Is there any problem if you set another image instead of this 9 patch ??

Comment: @user3596211 if "No" then i assume your patch image have problem thats why ide cant recognize

Comment: @user3596211 let me inform please

Comment: if i use logo.9.png there is no error 

then what is the prob into splc.9.png

Comment: @user3596211 okay .let me inform did you rename it as logo.9.png or its totally another image .if another image then i sure its your 9 patch image drawbacks

Comment: @user3596211 Please see my edited answer.I hope it works

Comment: Sir i use name bg.9.png it will give error and also error In R.

Comment: @user3596211 remove all 9 patch image (give backup..hahahaha)from folder and create 9 patch from https://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/nine-patches.html

Answer (score 0):

`@drawable/spc` is probably not a 9-patch(has no black pixels on the frame), so one possible fix will be to change **spc.9.png** to **spc.png**